# how to connect datafactory activities with python

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

i am following this tutorial
[quickstart tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python)

is great since teach how to use python to generate a data-factory resource, a pipeline and one activity, but if i need more than one, how do i connect them?

i assume that the azure portal and activities is just a  nice UI to generate a json file that have all the information of what activity is connected to another one?

how i can connect the output of an activity to the input of another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **CopyActivity** used in the tutorial you are following provides the **depends_on** parameter, which can be used to connect activities within the pipeline, for example:

> *If* activity **A** *depends on* activity **B** *then* activity **B** will be executed prior to activity **A** in the pipeline.
>
> Moreover, activity **A** will only be executed *if* activity **B**
>   succeeds.

Find more details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.copyactivity?view=azure-python.

Comment: oh! so all the activities will have the .depend_on([another_class_activity])   ?

Comment: Yes, they will inherit it from Activity. Find more details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.activity_py3.activity?view=azure-python. For example, CopyActivity inheritance chain is Activity -> ExecutionActivity -> CopyActivity.